# Airflow backfill breaks catchup=True

Tags: airflow

I'm wondering how exactly `airflow backfill` works, as it would help explain some trouble I had with Airflow. Is it just launching some kind of scheduler process that doesn't consider the rest of the DAGs and overrides the start_date and end_date? Or is it more than that?

My use case: I sometimes want to rerun a week for one DAG, typically when I added some new features to it. For this, I use the CLI (`airflow clear`) to clear the task instances for the dates desired. But sometimes also, I might change my mind, thinking it's not the right time to rerun this week. So I pause the DAG, and use command `airflow backfill -m` to set the cleared task instances as success.

When I do this, the concerned task instances get in a "broken" state regarding the `catchup=True` behavior. If I clear them again, they never get scheduled, although their DAG run is in state "running" (they keep None state). I've done several tests, and I'm 90% sure the `airflow backfill` is the culprit.

After all it seems logical that I shouldn't use `airflow backfill` on a DAG that has `catchup=True`, but that's my only way of marking sucess for a large set of task instances. Does someone know if this command modifies the state of the DAG run, appart from setting it to running? I somehow have the feeling it replaces its catchup settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I think I get it.

TL;DR >> The scheduler doesn't run task instances that have their DAG run prefixed with `backfill_`

The `backfill` command launches a [BackfillJob](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py), which will create DAG runs for the dates specified. In my case, it actually updates the existing DAG runs for these dates. When doing this, it updates the run_id of these DAG runs, replacing the `scheduled__` prefix with a `backfill_` one.

Now if I clear the DAG run again, the task instances will get None state, and my DAG run will get running. But when checking whether the task instances should be run, the scheduler won't consider them, although the DAG run is in running state, because this DAG run has the `backfill_` prefix in its ID. This is what the `if run.is_backfill` does in the `_process_task_instances` method of [SchedulerJob](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py)

Might be nice to have a note about this in the UI instead of the usual "this task instance has all dependencies met and should run soon" message :)

Comment: I had a question. Say I want to run a backfill job for a date that comes after the start_date but has no subsequent `scheduled` or `manual` runs for that date. Does the backfill run successfully ?(currently its failing, overriding failed scheduled/manual runs with `backfill_` prefix, without logs !!). What do I need to understand to run backfill successfully (even for a single date: catchup set to False) ??